# Probability Question Not Replaced Question

Tags: probability

I'm stuck behind the logic of this probability question -

> In an experiment, 6 bulbs were planted in a row. 3 produced red flowers and 3 produced yellow flowers.
>   If the bulbs were planted in a random order, what is the probability that the colours will alternate along the whole row?
>   
>  **[A] 1/60**
>   
>  **[B] 1/48**
>   
>  **[C] 1/32**
>   
>  **[D] 1/20**
>   
>  **[E] 1/10**

I thought based on the first evidence, the probability of blue and yellow are $\frac{3}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$ respectively, 
so I did the following:

Knowing that the only possiblities are RYRYRY and YRYRYR in a line, 
I did the calculation

$$2 \times (\frac{1}{2})^6 = \frac{1}{32}$$

but this is apparently incorrect. The answer is $\frac{1}{10}$ given by the calculation

$$2 \times \frac{3}{6} \times \frac{3}{5} \times \frac{2}{4} \times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{1} = \frac{1}{10}$$

I'm slightly puzzled. How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 
$$
\binom{6}{3} = 20
$$
ways to arrange three red and three yellow flowers in a row - choose the $3$ places for the red ones. In just $2$ of those the colors alternate.

Answer (score 1):

For the answer you have quoted, consider the ordering RYRYRY.  The probability the first flower is red is 3/6, because there are 6 flowers of which 3 are red.  Then the probability the second flower is yellow is 3/5, because there are 5 flowers left, out of which 3 are yellow.  Then the probability that the third flower is red is 2/4, because there are 4 flowers left of which 2 are red.  Etc.

Finally, multiply by 2 to account for the two equally likely orderings, RYRYRY and YRYRYR.